# 2EMA with arrows on Renko chart

Tags: pine-script

I am new to Pine Script and I was just trying to create a little script, however it fails and I just don't get why.

```
//@version=3
study(title="2EMA cross", shorttitle="2EMA cross", overlay=true)
EMA1 = input(2, minval=1, title="EMA1")
EMA2 = input(5, minval=1, title="EMA2"),

long = EMA1[1] > EMA2[1]
short = EMA2[1] > EMA1[1]

//Use these alerts to create server-side alerts (right-click on one of the buy or sell arrows on the chart and choose "add alert")
alertcondition(long, title='Buy Call', message='EMA long reversal')
alertcondition(short, title='Buy Put', message='EMA short reversal')

//EMA COLORS
plot(ema(close, EMA1), color=green, linewidth=2)
plot(ema(close, EMA2), color=red, linewidth=2)


//Use this to customize the look of the arrows to suit your needs.
plotshape(long, location=location.belowbar, color=lime, style=shape.arrowup, text="Call")
plotshape(short, location=location.abovebar, color=red, style=shape.arrowdown, text="Put")
```

This is the message I get:

```
line 14: Cannot call `ema` with arguments (series, series[integer]); available overloads: ema(series, integer) => series;
line 15: Cannot call `ema` with arguments (series, series[integer]); available overloads: ema(series, integer) => series
```

All I am trying to do is: Green arrow up + Call text on next brick after fast ema crosses above slow ema and same other way around with Put text + Red arrow down
[image: Screenshot]

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See comments in code:

```
//@version=3
study(title="2EMA cross", shorttitle="2EMA cross", overlay=true)
// These are only your ema periodds—not the emas themselves.
EMA1 = input(2, minval=1, title="EMA1")
EMA2 = input(5, minval=1, title="EMA2")

// Create the two ema calculations here and then use the results to detect signals and plot.
ema1    = ema(close, EMA1)
ema2    = ema(close, EMA2)

// Detect only the moment when the 2 emas cross, otherwise you would be getting one of the two signals at any given moment.
// Note that detecting occurs at the bar following the actual cross.
long    = crossover(ema1, ema2)
short   = crossunder(ema1, ema2)

// Use these alerts to create server-side alerts (right-click on one of the buy or sell arrows on the chart and choose "add alert")
alertcondition(long, title='Buy Call', message='EMA long reversal')
alertcondition(short, title='Buy Put', message='EMA short reversal')

// EMA COLORS
plot(ema1, color=green, linewidth=2)
plot(ema2, color=red, linewidth=2)


// Use this to customize the look of the arrows to suit your needs.
plotshape(long, location=location.belowbar, color=lime, style=shape.arrowup, text="Call")
plotshape(short, location=location.abovebar, color=red, style=shape.arrowdown, text="Put")
```

[image]

Using 1 minute Renko bars is not as bad as using longer timeframes, but it's still risky. These links may help understand why:
https://www.tradingview.com/script/q9laJNG9-Backtesting-on-Non-Standard-Charts-Caution-PineCoders-FAQ/

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000480330

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000481029